# Do I need admin privileges to read Windows file system change journal?

Tags: synchronization, filesystems, journal

I am creating synchronization software and I want to use the file system journal API for this. My application should install from the Windows Store and run under regular user permissions, without admin privileges. It will access only files under the C:\Users\USERNAME\ folder, which does not require admin rights. However, the [Keeping an Eye on Your NTFS Drives: the Windows 2000 Change Journal Explained](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-2000-server/bb742450(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#usage) article from the year 2009 says that my app needs admin privileges:

> Access to this volume handle is restricted to the system and members of the Administrators group, so typical users will not be able to run Change Journal applications. This means that these applications will most likely be services or utilities run by administrators.

Is this still true for Windows 11? Can I read the Windows file system change journal without admin rights?